# Auto Increment Primary Key Integrity

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I have a table with a `post` column and an auto incrementing `id` column. My `id` column is set as primary key. Is it bad practice to delete certain posts causing the `id` column to become unorganized?

Comment: No thats just fine.

Comment: Primary key just needs to be unique and (preferably) integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primary key is only for uniquely **identifying** a record. If you need specific **order** of your records then use an extra column for that. For instance a `datetime` column.